# Retrofit Android Api Call Show Blank Activity

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I was try to consume a Nested JSON API with Retrofit and GSON. The code has no error. But the problem is it's show blank Activity when i run the application. I used AndroidX layout for layout_activity, And Used RecyclerView for List.

here is the full code, please check it for me as if i can go ahead.

MyActivity

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new 
        LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {

        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        apiInterface.getMovies().enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Contact> contactList = response.body().getContacts();

                    for (int i = 0; i<contactList.size(); i++) {
                       adapter = new DataAdapter((ArrayList<Contact>) contactList);
                       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Server Error");
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Model Class Phone

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Phone {

    @SerializedName("mobile")
    @Expose
    private String mobile;

    @SerializedName("home")
    @Expose
    private String home;

    @SerializedName("office")
    @Expose
    private String office;

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getHome() {
        return home;
    }

    public void setHome(String home) {
        this.home = home;
    }

    public String getOffice() {
        return office;
    }

    public void setOffice(String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }
}
```

Model Class Contact

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Contact {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;

    @SerializedName("gender")
    @Expose
    private String gender;

    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private Phone phone;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Phone getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Class Movie

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Movie {
    @SerializedName("contacts")
    @Expose

    private List<Contact> contacts = null;

    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts){
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }
}
```

API Client Class

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {

    public static  final String BASE_URL="https://api.androidhive.info";
    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;


    public static final Retrofit getClient(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

DataAdapter Class

```
package com.example.retrofitnested;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Contact> arrayList;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_id.setText(arrayList.get(i).getId());
        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(arrayList.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_email.setText(arrayList.get(i).getEmail());
        viewHolder.tv_address.setText(arrayList.get(i).getAddress());
        viewHolder.tv_gender.setText(arrayList.get(i).getGender());

        viewHolder.tv_mobile.setText(arrayList.get(i).getPhone().getMobile());
        viewHolder.tv_home.setText(arrayList.get(i).getPhone().getHome());
        viewHolder.tv_office.setText(arrayList.get(i).getPhone().getOffice());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_id, tv_name, tv_email, tv_address, tv_gender, tv_mobile, tv_home, tv_office;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            tv_address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            tv_gender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
            tv_mobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mobile);
            tv_home = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.home);
            tv_office = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_office);

        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

card_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_address"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_gender"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_mobile"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_home"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_office"

            android:textSize="16sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.retrofitnested"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'


    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"




}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.retrofitnested">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RetrofitNested">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
2021-09-07 07:32:45.859 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-09-07 07:32:45.861 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-09-07 07:32:43.046 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-07 07:32:43.086 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-09-07 07:32:43.089 9923-9923/? W/.retrofitneste: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
        at auct.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):22)
        at anen.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):19)
2021-09-07 07:32:43.046 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-07 07:32:43.086 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-09-07 07:32:43.089 9923-9923/? W/.retrofitneste: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-09-07 07:32:45.859 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-09-07 07:32:43.046 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-09-07 07:32:43.086 9923-9923/? I/.retrofitneste: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-09-07 07:32:43.089 9923-9923/? W/.retrofitneste: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-09-07 07:32:45.859 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-09-07 07:32:47.205 9923-9959/com.example.retrofitnested D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-09-07 07:32:47.359 9923-9959/com.example.retrofitnested D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-09-07 07:32:47.502 9923-9959/com.example.retrofitnested D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-09-07 07:32:47.948 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Verification of androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleEventObserver androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling.lifecycleEventObserver(java.lang.Object) took 152.030ms (795.89 bytecodes/s) (2432B approximate peak alloc)
2021-09-07 07:32:48.467 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Verification of void androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean) took 153.953ms (58.46 bytecodes/s) (896B approximate peak alloc)
2021-09-07 07:32:49.768 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Verification of void androidx.appcompat.R$layout.<init>() took 112.475ms (35.56 bytecodes/s) (736B approximate peak alloc)
2021-09-07 07:32:49.867 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested I/.retrofitneste: IncrementDisableThreadFlip blocked for 95.648ms
2021-09-07 07:32:50.833 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:50.835 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:51.648 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:52.119 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:52.120 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:52.120 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-07 07:32:52.792 9923-9972/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Verification of boolean okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.hasNextProxy() took 132.199ms (105.90 bytecodes/s) (960B approximate peak alloc)
2021-09-07 07:32:53.616 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf26e2f30, tid 9958
2021-09-07 07:32:53.671 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2021-09-07 07:32:53.698 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2021-09-07 07:32:53.846 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf26e1e20: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2021-09-07 07:32:53.852 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf26e1e20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf2a17610) (first time)
2021-09-07 07:32:53.995 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2021-09-07 07:32:54.012 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-09-07 07:32:54.015 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf26e2360, tid 9958
2021-09-07 07:32:54.017 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2021-09-07 07:32:54.021 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x38fffe000 size 0x2000
2021-09-07 07:32:54.059 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2021-09-07 07:32:55.143 9923-9937/com.example.retrofitnested I/.retrofitneste: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2691(167KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 2729KB/5458KB, paused 7.201ms total 885.483ms
2021-09-07 07:32:56.044 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=3338ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=6193055405074, Vsync=6193288738398, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=6193303389500, AnimationStart=6193303566800, PerformTraversalsStart=6193303917200, DrawStart=6194443788000, SyncQueued=6194448390800, SyncStart=6194466515800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=6194467068800, SwapBuffers=6195908458000, FrameCompleted=6196411989700, DequeueBufferDuration=627200, QueueBufferDuration=4017500, GpuCompleted=72904454231491230, 
2021-09-07 07:32:56.352 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested W/.retrofitneste: Verification of androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.findItemWithShortcutForKey(int, android.view.KeyEvent) took 196.805ms (528.44 bytecodes/s) (2352B approximate peak alloc)
2021-09-07 07:32:57.432 9923-9923/com.example.retrofitnested I/Choreographer: Skipped 265 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-09-07 07:32:57.604 9923-9958/com.example.retrofitnested I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=4594ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=6193372077495, Vsync=6197788743985, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=6197800359900, AnimationStart=6197800549500, PerformTraversalsStart=6197801008300, DrawStart=6197805360500, SyncQueued=6197808308100, SyncStart=6197813106200, IssueDrawCommandsStart=6197813446600, SwapBuffers=6197819007600, FrameCompleted=6197971534600, DequeueBufferDuration=4388800, QueueBufferDuration=28498400, GpuCompleted=43984843964424,
```

Comment: Are you getting response from api successfully? Just log the contents of contact list to check whether your getting response from api

Comment: Please, add your AndroidManifest.xml to your question

Comment: @AlonsoAtoNeyra Manifest file added

Comment: Can we see what does your logcat says when you run your app? Usually, the logcat tell your a responde code 200, 400, etc. We need that and also your API Client class is showing the interface. Please, update your question

Comment: Added The Logcat , please check it

Comment: @AlonsoAtoNeyra API Client Class Updated Please check it